# Can I delete an element in one place, and create an element elsewhere in one go?

Tags: htmx

I have 2 parent elements, let's call them div_parent_1 and div_parent_2.  Both of these parent elements have a number of child elements.

I want to use htmx to move a child element from div_parent_1 to div_parent_2 without reloading all the contents of either div.

I am struggling to explain what I need in a generic way. My actual use case is: I'm building a Kanban board and I would like to move a card from one column to another without needing to re-render the whole board.

Note: I am not asking about dragging and dropping. I want the user to click a button. Then one element should get deleted and a new element (with different html) should appear somewhere else.

Comment: It is possible to use draggable js library with htmx, you just need to figure out how to integrate it. You can look into the following example for some inspiration: https://htmx.org/examples/sortable/

Comment: @mariodev thanks for trying to help. That's not what I need at all though. I need a thing to get deleted in one place and then a new thing (that looks slightly different) to appear in a differnt place when a user clicks a button.   Drag and drop isn't something I'm looking at right now

Comment: Someone edited my question and removed relevant details. I can see why you though drag and drop was what I was looking for.  I'm fixing the question.

Comment: No worries. I wasn't really trying to prvide the exact answer on how to do it.. My point was that you can check the example to see how you can create integration with 3rd party libraries using htmx, which I guess smth like draggable.js and htmx could work.

Comment: Everyday I see people trying to force htmx to manipulate the DOM in ways it wasn't primarily made for. Please, take a look at [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/) instead. Hyperscript, created by the same guys who created htmx, was especially created for manipulating the DOM by following the same philosophy as that of htmx.

Comment: Thanks @McPherson , I'll take a look.  I was thinking I could probably use htmx's multi-swap stuff to get this right, but I think there is something I'm not quite understanding. I'm very new to htmx, basically started learning it 2 days ago when I asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most graceful way to do things, but it works.

My HTML looks like this:

(I'm using Django templating if you aren't familiar with it, then you just need to know that the stuff in the curly braces gets replaced with real values)

```
<div id="card_{{ card.id }}" 
    
    ... important stuff the user wants so see

    <button
        hx-post="{{start_card_url}}"
        hx-target="#card_{{ card.id }}"
        hx-swap="outerHTML"
        >Start
    </button>
</div>
```

So I do a Post to the start card endpoint and then replace the card div with whatever comes back.

The response from the "start_card" endpoint is something like this:

```
<div id="card_{{ card.id }}" 
    ... basically the same as before, some updated values, different buttons
</div>

<script>
    moveCardToCorrectColumn("{{card.id}}","{{card.status}}")
</script>
```

So it's the whole card, and a function call to immediately move the card to where it should be based on its status.